# Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded. firebase functions issue

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy new functions in my firebase project but it started showing an error. I have 5 functions in my index.js file and at any given point, 4 functions are getting deployed and one is throwing this error.

```
⚠  functions[whenUserIsAdded]: Deployment error.
Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'firebase-functions'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/index.js:1:79)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

This happens every time to any one of the 5 functions and this happens in random. I deployed the same code about 2 hours ago and it went smooth. Now after adding some console.log statements, it is showing this error at random with a function.

Can anybody help me with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Also, I am on the blaze plan.

Comment: Did you try deploying it in another project and checking?

Comment: do you have firebase-admin and firebase-functions included in package.json.? if yes, what version ?

Comment: Yes. I tried deploying it in another project. Our staging project. It worked and the functions were triggered. I am not being able to deploy in the production project.

Comment: @Muthukumar Yes. I have them included in the project.

    "firebase-admin": "^5.2.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.6.3",

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I think I found the issue. I was having firebase-functions V0.6.3. I believe that was depreciated. Hence it was not working I updated my package.json to the following and it worked. Because functions is still in Beta, I dont think we can do anything about this.

```
"firebase-admin": "~5.4.2",
"firebase-functions": "^0.7.1",
```

Comment: The latest versions of those libraries at the time of this writing are 5.5.1 and 0.7.3.  Be sure to keep them up to date.

Comment: Sure I will. Thanks.